# When lock Is release on object in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have one function  in model class and inside that function I am doing like this,

```
def myfun
  .... 
  self.lock!
  self.name = "hi" 
  .... 
  .... 
 end
```

So on above case when will lock release from object?

And here Note : I am not writing this inside the transactions block.

Comment: Can’t test it right now, but I’d guess that without an explicit transaction block, the lock will be released right-away. Take a look at the Rails log – it should help to understand what’s happening under the hood.

Comment: @Stefan you're correct,  the lock will be released right-away.

Answer (score 4):

[ActiveRecord::Locking::Pessimistic](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html) is made to be used with transactions, which means that `lock!` should be called inside a transaction and the lock will be released when the transaction commits or rolls back.

You can also use `with_lock do ... end` to create the transaction and lock the field automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`ActiceRecord#lock!` won't lock any `object` as you thought, it'll call [`reload(lock: true)`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/locking/pessimistic.rb) which append the end of the SELECT statement or pass true for "FOR UPDATE" that mean an sql `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` will be called so that a database lock (an exclusive row lock ?, depend on database) be created, return a locked record, that is what `lock!` imply for, not lock the object.

```rb
q = Question.first 
# SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" ORDER BY "questions"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  ...
q.lock! 
# SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2 FOR UPDATE ...
```

And that lock will be released after the select query done.